# How do I use ruby-debug inside Emacs?

Tags: ruby, debugging, emacs

I know Emacs has some sort of integration with gdb (though I never used it) to jump through files as you debug a program. I'd like to do the same with Ruby programs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As erenon said, use ruby debug, which provides a library for emacs that lets you use it just as gdb.

Install rdebug by issuing this command on your terminal(the sudo is optional, depending on your system):

```
<sudo> gem install ruby-debug
```

You then need to [download](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/46883/ruby-debug-extra-0.10.3.tar.gz) the ruby-debug-extra file from rubyforge, and install it in the standard way.

```
  sh ./configure
  make
  make test # optional, but a good idea
  sudo make install
```

This gives you the elisp files for the interaction with rdebug, plus documentation for ruby-debug that can be viewed from within emacs.

**AJ**

Comment: Thanks! As a note, I also had to install (in Ubuntu) the packages `texi2html` and `texinfo` before compiling `ruby-debug-extra`, but it worked.

Answer (score 6):

There is another emacs to ruby-debug interface. See https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/wiki .

More generally, it works with other ruby debuggers and other debuggers in general.

Answer (score 1):

You may want use rdebug.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting "Cannot open load file: gdb-ui" in GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0.0, NS apple-appkit-1038.11) of 2009-10-31

Comment: Did you ever come up with a workaround for this?  I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: It looks like `gdb-ui` is no longer part of Emacs. My version 24 doesn't include them. On Mac OS X (as you are running, but I use 10.8), I found copies here: `/usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp/progmodes/gdb-ui.el.gz`, `/usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp/progmodes/gdb-ui.elc` and they still seem to work with a new version of emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with same problem with gdb-ui, but I found the solution: I downloaded gdb-ui.el from [here](http://www.koders.com/lisp/fidB9BE3F5F4DE307CC995C14E11A3B443DA1364955.aspx?s=TV+Raman#L66) and put it into ruby-debug-extra/emacs dir... then I've adjusted Makefiles to point to this file before any other rdebug*.el files. After this step you'll get make working. Since I'm using emacs-snapshot and gdb mode is available already in my emacs environment, this issue is only about to build rdebug mode. After this I've installed it with "sudo make install" and it works perfectly :) Don't forget to add (require 'rdebug) to your ~/.emacs or whatever else you use to bootstrap your config.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen strategy can be made to work, although texi2html and texinfo were not enough on my system, but I stopped pursuing this strategy without installing the extra packages.

Here's what I did: download ruby-debug-extra-0.10.4.tar.gz from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=1900&release_id=28306, untar it, but DON'T do the whole configure/make/blah/blah thing.  Instead, I simply copied the 'emacs' directory to ~/.emacs.d/rdebug, and then added to my ~/.emacs.d/init.el file (you can also use your ~/.emacs file):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/rdebug")
(autoload 'rdebug "rdebug" "ruby-debug interface" t)
```

This won't byte-compile it, I didn't care.  I prefer this solution because I got really annoyed that the packages forces you to install the docs.